# Baking leaves dark area

Tags: texturing, shaders, texture-painting, texture-baking, displacement

I'm trying to bake a texture and whenever I bake, It bakes normally except for the spot with metallic, roughness, displacement and base color. here is what it looks like normally and what the bake result is:

[image]

[image]

I tried experimenting with different bake types like combined and diffuse and added my own light sources and made them super bright but still won't work.